# how to get each value from a div which contains values more than two in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get each value one by one from the div using jquery, below is my code

```
<div class="vouchers-entered-wrapper">
    <div id="enteredVoucher_" 1="">
        <div class="col-md-3 voucher-value-append">1234</div>
        <div class="col-md-1 voucher-value-delete">Delete</div>
    </div>
    <div id="enteredVoucher_" 2="">
        <div class="col-md-3 voucher-value-append">2345</div>
        <div class="col-md-1 voucher-value-delete">Delete</div>
    </div>
    <div id="enteredVoucher_" 3="">
        <div class="col-md-3 voucher-value-append">3456</div>
        <div class="col-md-1 voucher-value-delete">Delete</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to take each value for validation to avoid duplicate entry

Comment: what do you mean by value... do you mean `1234`, `2345` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the values from the `voucher-value-append` you need to loop using `each` over all the divs inside `vouchers-entered-wrapper` as follow:

```
var values = [];
$('.vouchers-entered-wrapper').children('div').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).find('.voucher-value-append').text();

    if (values.indexOf(value) == -1)
        values.push(value);
    else
        alert('Duplicate Value');
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5w0c4fxa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple loop:

```
$('.vouchers-entered-wrapper').each(function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Where `$('.vouchers-entered-wrapper')` selects your parent div by its class, `.each(function(index, value) {` creates a for-each loop for each item, capturing the value, which in this case is the element content and `console.log(value);` is where you use these values.

I'm not checking in they are blank, which might benefit your cause, since logging the value shows only the ones that do have values.

http://jsfiddle.net/m0sbhek9/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over the `voucher-value-append` elements

```js
$('.vouchers-entered-wrapper .voucher-value-append').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vouchers-entered-wrapper">
  <div id="enteredVoucher_" 1="">
    <div class="col-md-3 voucher-value-append">1234</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 voucher-value-delete">Delete</div>
  </div>
  <div id="enteredVoucher_" 2="">
    <div class="col-md-3 voucher-value-append">2345</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 voucher-value-delete">Delete</div>
  </div>
  <div id="enteredVoucher_" 3="">
    <div class="col-md-3 voucher-value-append">3456</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 voucher-value-delete">Delete</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: Your ID attributes looks odd, check whether they are created properly